# Tracking Eclipse JDT Compiler Error Messages (IProblem)

Tags: java, eclipse, workspace, eclipse-jdt

I am currently developing programming tutors. Those tutors are standalone Java applications. I use Eclipse JDT to parse Java source code and build the corresponding abstract syntax tree. Moreover, I want to capture the error messages that would be launched if a student would compile his code within Eclipse. Eclipse enables us to parse and track error messages for a specific string of code (without context). After having "compiled" that string, I got 9 error messages. When I pasted that code within an Eclipse project, I got around 90 error messages. Obviously, the purpose is to track as much errors as possible. I suspect that it depends on the context of the source code.

For that purpose, I tried to create programmatically a project within the workspace and create a file containing the source code string. However, when executing my Java application I get the following error message:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Workspace is closed.
    at org.eclipse.core.resources.ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace(ResourcesPlugin.java:399)
    at com.example.helloworld.JavaErr.main(JavaErr.java:67)
```

I read many articles on this topic. It seems like we can access resources within the workspace only within an Eclipse plugin project. Before giving up that "solution" path, would it be possible to know if we can access the workspace and all its resources programmatically within an external standalone Java application?

Answer (score 0):

I needed finally to resolve the bindings between the char[] source code and its environment (setEnvironment), and set the name of the compilation unit. Setting the environment enables us to bypass the workspace and create our own "virtual" project by importing the proper libraries (classpath) and the source code (sourcepath).

If somebody would like to also retrieve syntax errors, he has only to enable the recovery of statements. Thus we are able to parse an external Java file in a standalone Java application and retrieve the same amount of errors as it would in a real Eclipse project (except for the package declaration error).

Here is the code fragment I used:

```
        File file = new File("");
        String srcCode = Files.toString(file, Charsets.UTF_8);
        ASTParser parser = ASTParser.newParser(AST.JLS3);
        parser.setSource(srcCode.toCharArray());
        parser.setKind(ASTParser.K_COMPILATION_UNIT);
        Map options = JavaCore.getOptions();
        JavaCore.setComplianceOptions(JavaCore.VERSION_1_5, options);
        parser.setCompilerOptions(options);

        String[] classpath = {"", "", ""};
        String[] sourcepath = {""};

        parser.setEnvironment(classpath, sourcepath, null, true);
        parser.setUnitName("");
        parser.setResolveBindings(true);
        parser.setBindingsRecovery(true);
        parser.setStatementsRecovery(true);
        CompilationUnit cu = (CompilationUnit) parser.createAST(null);
        cu.accept(new ASTVisitor2(cu));
```

Answer (score 0):

For accessing a workspace as such using jdt, see the updated answer to the below question:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15997775/extracting-variables-and-their-type-names-including-class-method-variables-fro/16006559#16006559